# Android: Converting an image's pixel height to DP?

Tags: android

I got an image I created in Photoshop that is 300 X 300 pixels. I need to create a text label that is the same height. I know I shouldn't set it to 300px, as we should use dp. So how do I convert the 300 pixels to dp, so I know what to set the height as?

I know it's possible to relatively align the text label to the right of the image, but ignore that for now... how can I determine what height in dp to set the text label so it's the same height as the image?

Comment: Do you display the image as 300px or 300dp on the screen. Do you scale the image or not and should the textview still have the same size or not?

Comment: the textview should have the same size. I'm not scaling the image, just putting it directly in the view

Comment: I think you have to set a height 300px for the textview since the image will always be 300px. Of course that means it will be bigger on low res screens and smaller on high res screens in terms of millimeters/centimeters.

Comment: If I decide to scale the image to the different screen densities, is the height DP = 300 for mdp screens?

Comment: Depends on what quality you consider your image to be. Is it a ldpi, mdpi or hdpi image? Should it be scaled up or down.

Comment: it's a mdpi image. I'm gonna scale it up for the hdpi screens and down for the ldpi screens.

Comment: In that case your 300px image got a height of 300dp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`TypedValue.applyDimension(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension%28int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics%29)